# How to check if database master is available on postgres 9.5?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have postgres 9.5 database with one master and two replicas. My project is on c++.
To check if master instance is available I run mock query. Is there more convenient way to do this?

UPD: I know about instruments which can be used in terminal such as systemctl and pg_isready, but they are not applicable to use from c++ project

Comment: `PQconnectdb()`.

Answer (score 0):

We use [repmgr](https://repmgr.org) to keep an eye on all clusters and to manage the primary and secondary databases.

But version 9.5, are you sure? That's EOL for a pretty long time. Plan a move to version 14.